# Seeking guidance on calculating the volume of a four-dimensional cone

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, volume, solid-geometry

I'm working on a problem involving a four-dimensional cone defined as follows:
$C = \left\{\left(x,y,z,t\right)| (x,y,z) \in (1 - \frac{t}{12})B,0 \leq t \leq 12\right\}$
where the base $B$ is described by $x^2 + (y - 1)^2 + z^2 \leq 1$. I'm tasked with finding the volume (measure) of $\mu(C)$.
I understand that the base $B$ is a three-dimensional ball centered at $(0,1,0)$ with a radius of 1. However, I'm unsure how to approach calculating the volume of this four-dimensional cone based on this information.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to compute the volume of this four-dimensional cone? Any step-by-step approach or insights into higher-dimensional geometry would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Cavalieri's principle applies in arbitrary dimension. Here, each slice $t = \text{constant}$ is a solid $3$-ball whose radius is known (and $t$-dependent). The "shearing" along the $y$-axis merely translates the cross-sections, which does not affect the volume.